# Reuse gRPC connection/channel when multiple names resolve to the same IPs

Tags: grpc

Is there a way to configure/setup multiple gRPC clients to share connections/channels if two or more names/targets resolve to the same remote address (or addresses)?

For example, say I was using the dns name resolver, if `dns://service-a` and `dns://service-b` both resolve to `[12.34.56.78]` I'd like gRPC to know this and decide to only open a single connection to the backend `12.34.56.78`.

Comment: AFAIK gRPC C core is already doing that. What language are you using?

Comment: Java and go (both servers and clients). I tested it by checking the source address of requests that reach the server and noticed that each client had a unique source port

Comment: This is not currently possible in Java and Go.

Comment: @EricAnderson any updates on this?